# Why does English use the present continuous so often?

Tags: present-tense, progressive-aspect

Why is the present continuous used in English so often in comparison to the simple present?

For example

> I eat

is possible, but the preferred way

> I am eating

meaning roughly the same thing, is much more complicated.

In most languages, the simple present is the standard form. But in English, the more complicated form is favored.

Why has the more wordy present continuous mostly displaced a simpler form verb?

Comment: This makes no sense: a gerund ***is*** a verb! Please edit your question to provide several concrete examples of whatever it is you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry my fault! The question is why that verb form has become so popular?

Comment: You have to explain further, give an example where you think the gerund is unnecessary. Or "prove" that gerunds are overtaking the English language?! Where did you get this idea? Are you perhaps stuck on gerunds versus participles?

Comment: Are you saying that using verbs in roles normally served by substantives like in **"Eating hamburgers** is very hard for me" or "I like **eating hot dogs"** or **"To eat hot dogs** is very hard for me" or "I like **to eat hamburgers"** somehow has those non-finite verb clauses “replacing” a finite verb clause? How so? How would you use *eat* as an inflected, finite verb that expresses the same thought? Try it with "she eats" and see where that leads you.

Comment: @tchrist or the OP could be interested in why 'I am eating hotdogs' is more common than 'I eat hotdogs'. But the OP needs to edit to clarify and give examples.

Comment: Other languages don't use it so extensively.

Comment: Are you talking about why English says "I am eating" rather than the normal "I eat" more commonly found in other languages?

Comment: I mean why the longer form was chosen over the shorter form for a more frequent usage case. And even more strange: why a lot of native English speakers tend to use that longer form even in those cases when it shouldn't be used.

Comment: @ivanavdeyev Well, Spanish, Portuguese, and Italian ***can*** use "be" plus a gerund in their progressive forms like English almost always does, so like Spanish "Estoy **comiendo"** for "I am (in the process of) eating". But that's not the normal case in those languages like it is in English; there, it draws special attention to the progressive aspect. I'm pretty sure that we have some questions about this here; let me see if I can't hunt those down for you.

Comment: Usually such natural things as human languages tend "to optimize" themselves over the time. The inverse way looks a bit strange. A lot of languages use a gerund but its usage is very limited (unlike English which uses it extensively and it seems tends to employ it even more). Maybe that situation somehow is related to the situation with letters/sounds discrepancy in English?

Comment: Here are some related questions:  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/218460 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/59292  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/65687 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10144 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/92014 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/106229 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/150616 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/389585 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/177256 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/197145  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/95450

Comment: Thanks a lot for the related questions! And the answers as well of course.

Comment: Greek makes very extensive use of participles (and thus of 'gerunds'). The study of the Greek verb includes a whole section just on participles of all shapes and sizes (which includes 'gerunds').

Comment: @ivanavdeyev I took the liberty of rewording your question based on your comments, since you did not edit it yourself. I think you were misusing the word 'gerund' as it is the same form (-ing) as the present continuous.

Comment: @ivanavdeyev : In my thought, it depends on human's balancing habit. That is, if the sentence is long, then we minimize it. If the sentence is very short, then we maximize it a little.

Comment: @ivan I haven’t looked through the related questions linked to by tchrist, but I can at least tell you that, apart from the Romance languages, similar continuous constructions are very common in Irish and Scottish Gaelic and almost _exclusive_ in Welsh, where the simple present is very rare and archaic in regular use. The continuous stresses precisely that an action is _continuous_ or _ongoing_, as opposed to general or timeless, which is an exceedingly common thing to want to stress, and nearly all languages do it. English just happens to do it with participles.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for your claim that '_the present continuous is used in English so often in comparison to the simple present_? A simple Google search returns 24 million results for "_I eat_" and only 6 million for "_I am eating_" plus "_I'm eating_".

Comment: Gerund... now it's present continuous. There's a fair bit of difference between "***Eating honey*** *is supposed to be good for you*" and "***I'm*** always ***eating honey***" or "I'm eating honey now" or "***I eat honey*** *every day*". Which form are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

In English, 'I eat' is not actually a present tense, as such. The sentence :

> I eat.

only conveys the concept of a state of activity. It is something I do, as part of my existence, throughout my lifetime.

> I eat bread, I do not eat chicken ...

conveys a facet of my existence, an attribute of my humanity.

---

> I am eating ...

is a true present tense. I am eating, now, presently.

Even if I say :

> I am eating white bread this week and brown bread next week ...

it is still a present activity.

---

In my view, "I eat" can almost be regarded as an infinitive (in English).

Answer (score 1):

If I may, I'm going to cite the British Council (and [this specific page](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/fr/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-continuous)).

Present continuous is used:

- To talk about the present in the following cases:

→ for something that is happening at the moment of speaking

→for something which is happening before and after a given time (*At eight o’clock we are usually having breakfast*)

→ for something which we think is temporary (*I’m working in London for the next two weeks.*)

→ for something which is new and contrasts with a previous state (*These days most people are using email instead of writing letters.*)

→ to show that something is changing, growing or developing (*The children are growing quickly.*)

→ for something which happens again and again: (*He’s always laughing.*)

- To talk about the future in the following case

→ for something which has been arranged or planned (*I am going to the city this afternoon*)

Using "I eat" does not clearly carry a meaning of "I am doing the action of eating".

Comment: I'm not sure how this attempts to answer the given question. You may want to also explain the meaning of the simple present, and then attempt to explain how the present continuous is favored over the simple present (when they overlap in meaning or not).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is this:  where many other languages require the listener or reader to establish from context whether the message originator is specifying he is currently engaging in that activity or that, generally, he does but may or may not be doing so now ("Je conduis" tells you nothing about whether I simply know how to drive, or whether I am driving right this second), English has evolved to allow the distinction.  I think the distinction is a valuable one, even if it makes English harder to learn for native speakers of other languages.

Comment: I think "Je sais conduire" would most likely be used if you were saying you *know* how to drive.

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking That's true, technically, but in French, just as in English, you might say "I drive" as a way of saying that you are capable of driving.

Comment: You might well be right - it's not something I've encountered, though. I wonder if this is a difference between Canadian French and French French (!)?

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking It might be, although my French is a bit of an amalgam of that of France and Quebec (closer to the former).  A better example might be "I drive to work"; in French the translation of this would be ambiguous (except from context) about whether the person habitually gets to work by driving, or is actually driving to work at the moment, whereas in English this is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the way the language functions itself. On the other hand, **present continuous** is often used to talk about an action that´s taking place at the moment. There are other cases in which these could also be seen:
How are you doing?, for instance. It´s true that more than ever before, there´s been a tendency to choose the longer form, but I think it´s idiomatic...

Comment: The final clarification of my question: people use present continuous much more frequently but for it they have a special form of a verb. A longer form. Present simple is used quite rarely but uses a shorter form. It's really strange. "I eat" and "I am eating" obviously the latter is in 99% of all cases.